# While loop throwing error at the start of while

Tags: matrix, while-loop, octave

I want to take the user's input of a positive integer where `1 < a < 10^6` and run a loop on it and then store it in a matrix which gets printed to the screen. However, my code is throwing a **syntax** error pointing to the letter "e" in `while`. Does anyone know why this error is appearing?

```
A = (while (a!=1)
       If(rem(a,2)=0
          floor(a^(1/2));
       Else
          floor(a^(3/2));
    endwhile)

disp(A);
```

Comment: Never just say "an error". Please give the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

You're having several different problems in your code:

- a while loop doesn't return anything, so you can't assign it to `A`
- syntax is case sensitive, so it's `if` and `else`, not `If` and `Else`
- you're missing a closing brace after the if clause
- you're missing an `endif`
- you're assigning to `rem`, use `==` to compare for equality

Comment: Tried something else because I wasn't sure if the `if/else` within the while was going to work...See edited question.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you algorithm does never end, but that's a different problem and you shouldn't edit a question to change it's meaning completely but open a new one in such a case, so I'll revert your original question. Just a hint: you never change the value of `a` anywhere, so the conditions can never be met.